# Formatting alphanumeric string

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I have a string with 16 alphanumeric characters, e.g. F4194E7CC775F003. I'd like to format it as F419-4E7C-C775-F003.

I tried using

```
string.Format("{0:####-####-####-####}","F4194E7CC775F003");
```

but this doesn't work since it's not a numeric value.

So I came up with the following:

```
public class DashFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
  public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
  {
    return this;
  }

  public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
  {
    char[] chars = arg.ToString().ToCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
      if (i > 0 && i % 4 == 0)
      {
        sb.Append('-');
      }

      sb.Append(chars[i]);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```

and by using

```
string.Format(new DashFormatter(), "{0}", "F4194E7CC775F003");
```

I was able to solve the problem, however I was hoping there is a better/simpler way to do it? Perhaps some LINQ magic?

Thanks.

Comment: I thought this was pretty straightforward, but, sadly, it doesn't work: `string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}-{4}{5}{6}{7}-{8}{9}{10}{11}-{12}{13}{14}{15}", aString.ToCharArray());`

Comment: string.format requires a list of parameters. aString.ToCharArray() is seen as one array parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it in one line without Linq:

```
        StringBuilder  splitMe = new StringBuilder("F4194E7CC775F003");
        string joined = splitMe.Insert(12, "-").Insert(8, "-").Insert(4, "-").ToString();
```

Comment: +1 better than mine, and better than any of the LINQ solutions

Comment: I was wondering which was more efficient, your or mine, so I did a quick benchmark - yours is twice as fast ;-)

Comment: Nice, but I would argue that's two lines.

Comment: it can be rewritten in one line as string joined = new StringBuilder("F4194E7CC775F003").Insert(12, "-").Insert(8, "-").Insert(4, "-").ToString();

Comment: @Adam: How does the performance compare to the OP's solution?

Comment: I'll accept this answer, but I like hmemcpy's solution better. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a regular expression, though I don't know what the performance of this would be compared to the other methods.

```
string formattedString = Regex.Replace(yourString, "(\\S{4})\\B", "$1-");
```

You could put this in an extension method for string too, if you want to do:

```
yourString.ToDashedFormat();
```

Comment: sorry but this is 25 times slower than Carra's solution

Comment: Ouch! Well, I did say that I didn't know what the performance would be like!

Answer (score 1):

If you want it linq:

```
var formatted = string.Join("-", Enumerable.Range(0,4).Select(i=>s.Substring(i*4,4)).ToArray());
```

And if you want it efficient:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(19);
sb.Append(s,0,4);
for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++ )
{
 sb.Append('-');
 sb.Append(s,i*4, 4);
}
return sb.ToString();
```

I did not benchmark this one, but i think it would be faster then StringBuilder.Insert because it does not move the rest of string many times, it just writes 4 chars.
Also it would not reallocate the underlying string, because it's preallocated to 19 chars at the beginning.

Comment: but i think u r missing casting 

var s= string.Join("-", Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(i => "F4194E7CC775F003".Substring(i * 4, 4)).ToArray());

Comment: it may look like cool code, but it's very inefficient. I just did some benchmarks and Carra's solution is 3 times faster

Comment: Yeah, sorry, i din't try to compile, now it's corrected. I'm actually using my own extension for string, and it looks like foo.Select(bar).JoinWithSeparator('-')

Comment: Yes, i agree it's inefficient. The most efficient one would be working with arrays of chars in C++ style, not a string builder.

Comment: @George - "working with arrays of chars in C++ style" - I believe this is exactly what StringBuilder does internally

Comment: @AdamRalph  what tools you are using to get these statistics and comparison between different algorithms  ????

Comment: @TiTaN - Visual Studio and C# ;-) I just wrote a quick unit test which runs each method 100,000 times and compares the time taken

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Carra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287023/formatting-alphanumeric-string/2287139#2287139) I made this little utility method:

```
private static string ToDelimitedString(string input, int position, string delimiter)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);

  int x = input.Length / position;

  while (--x > 0)
  {
    sb = sb.Insert(x * position, delimiter);
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
string result = ToDelimitedString("F4194E7CC775F003", 4, "-");
```

And a test case:

```
[Test]
public void ReturnsDelimitedString()
{
  string input = "F4194E7CC775F003";

  string actual = ToDelimitedString(input, 4, "-");

  Assert.AreEqual("F419-4E7C-C775-F003", actual);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 char[] chars = "F4194E7CC775F003".ToCharArray();
            var str = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}"
                                  , new string(chars.Take(4).ToArray())
                                  , new string(chars.Skip(4).Take(4).ToArray())
                                  , new string(chars.Skip(8).Take(4).ToArray())
                                  , new string(chars.Skip(12).Take(4).ToArray())  
                );
```

Comment: Quite ugly, but LINQ indeed ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this looks horribly inefficient, like Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)

Comment: it's 8 times slower than Carra's solution

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution I can think of is

```
        var text = "F4194E7CC775F003";
        var formattedText = string.Format(
            "{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}",
            text.Substring(0, 4),
            text.Substring(4, 4),
            text.Substring(8, 4),
            text.Substring(12, 4));
```

Comment: Carra's solution is twice as fast

Answer (score 0):

Only 9 years later, a minor variation from Carra's answer. This yields about a 2.5x speed improvement based on my tests (change all "-" to '-'):

```
        StringBuilder initial = new StringBuilder("F4194E7CC775F003");
        return initial.Insert(12, '-').Insert(8, '-').Insert(4, '-').ToString();
```