# Format A String

Tags: c#, string, format

Well,

I just can't format the following string:

```
string oldFormat = "949123U0456789";
oldFormat = string.Format(@"{0: ###.###-##-###.###}",oldFormat);
```

the result should be: 949.123-U0-456.789

Does anyone have a better way to format this string?

Comment: `#` means numeral. You have a `U` in the middle of the string, which is not a numeral. Additionally, when passing in a string to `string.Format`, nothing will happen with the string - it will be returned as is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format string with dashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968845/format-string-with-dashes)

Comment: I found [this][1] here on stackoverflow. It uses LINQ.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287023/formatting-alphanumeric-string

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx):

```
"949123U0456789".Insert(11, ".").Insert(8, "-").Insert(6, "-").Insert(3, ".")
```

Note that I am inserting from the end, to avoid the addition of the inserted string from affecting the index.

The format string you have used is meant for numeric types - a string is not a numeric types (and when passing in a string to `string.Format`, it will simply be returned, as it already is a string).

There are other approaches, as can be seen in [Format string with dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3968845/1583):

Using regex:

```
Regex.Replace("949123U0456789",
              @"^(.{3})(.{3})(.{2})(.{3})(.{3})$",
              "$1.$2-$3-$4.$5");
```

Or with Substring.

Comment: Very Clever! People should point his attention in the order. Is very important follow the order, from back to front. Great and simple!

Answer (score 1):

Regex can solve the problem of formatting when there is a mix of letters and numbers.

```
        using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

        string pattern = @"([a-z0-9A-Z]{3})([a-z0-9A-Z]{3})
                    ([a-z0-9A-Z]{2})([a-z0-9A-Z]{3})([a-z0-9A-Z]{3})"
        string oldFormat = "949123U0456789";
        string newFormat = Regex.Replace(oldFormat, pattern, 
                    "$1.$2-$3-$4.$5");
```

I love regular expressions :D, they have the added benefit of allowing  you to check the syntax of the code, if it has to follow a certain convention (i.e. perform validation).

In order to perform validation, you can use:

```
        Regex.IsMatch(oldFormat, 
                    @"([a-z0-9A-Z]{3})([a-z0-9A-Z]{3})
                    ([a-z0-9A-Z]{2})([a-z0-9A-Z]{3})
                    ([a-z0-9A-Z]{3})")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s="949123U0456789";

Regex r=new Regex(@"(\w{3})(\w{3})(\w{2})(\w{3})(\w{3})");
Console.WriteLine(r.Replace(s,"$1.$2-$3-$4.$5"));
```